# Why does TypeScript consider each number its own type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

The expression `1==2` causes TypeScript to give the error `Operator '==' cannot be applied to types '1' and '2'`. What are the reasons for TypeScript treating these values as being of a different type (the `typeof` operator, rather predictably, says that they're both `number`s)? Is it a design decision to specifically apply this to numbers, or a byproduct of the overall typing system? What harm could be caused by allowing comparison of literals?

Comment: thats just because the numbers have different values, it's not a type problem

Comment: But then surely the expression would just return `false`, rather than causing the script to not compile?

Comment: Well, it *does* compile, just with a warning… but yes, interesting question. Here's a link to reproduce: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=1%20%3D%3D%202%3B

Comment: What could possibly be gained by comparing literals? You know that the comparison will always be `false`, so don't run the code at all.

Comment: @ZevSpitz "Why" is not really relevant to the question at hand. I'm asking about the design decision.

Comment: @deceze there are no warnings, that is an error, but the process will still emit the js, unless the `--noEmitOnError` flag is used

Comment: _What harm could be caused by allowing comparison of literals?_ I would suggest that features need justification to be put in a language, not just that they wouldn't cause any harm.

Comment: @Zev it's a valid and interesting question nonetheless.

Answer (score 7):

`1` and `2` in this context are considered so called literal numbers. It means that value `1` has type `1` and thus can only be `1`, same with `2`. Given that, the expression of `1==2` doesn't make sense because `1` can never be `2`, or more precisely their types mismatch, you can't compare apples to oranges.

Here are the rationale and in depth details on where literals types are assumed by default:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676

About literal types:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9407
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5185

One of many examples as to why literal types are useful:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9163

Comment: A bunch of singleton types with just one inhabitant aren't that useful. Why isn't a number literal just a polymorphic `Number` type like in untyped Javascript? This is a step back and quite disappointing. People shouldn't introduce a rigid, static type system without providing concepts to make it more flexible again.

Comment: there is no clear vision as to what is more beneficial: for some scenarios literal types work better for other scenarios they bring problems, here is more about it: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676

Comment: Regarding your _Why literal types are useful_ link: The tags of tagged unions don't have to be types themselves. They can just be kind of like constants. Haskell, ML, Swift, and Rust all take this approach and I am sure they do so for a good reason.

Comment: rephrased to avoid falling into conclusion that this is the sole purpose of literal types

Comment: @ftor when it comes to sum types TypeScript is way ahead of Haskell and ML simply because it delegates to you the problem of discriminating `Just` from `Nothing`, and if you are smart enough you can have a type that looks like `Just a | Right a` without making runtime choke

Answer (score 5):

When TypeScript peforms type inference on the expression `1`, it gives it the type `1`, not the type `number`. You can see this if you examine code like this:

```
const a = 1;
```

If you use your IDE to query the inferred type of `a`, you'll see that the type of a is `1`. In the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), for instance, you get a tooltip that says `const a: 1`.

So in `if (1 == 2)`, `1` has type `1` and `2` has type `2`. TypeScript does not allow you to compare them because they are of different inferred types. This is part of the type safety TypeScript gives you.

You *can* work around it with:

```
if (1 as number == 2) {
}
```

And you mentioned in a comment that you were doing the `1 == 2` comparison because you could not do `if (false) { ... }` due to the compiler complaining about unreachable code. I can work around that problem with this:

```
if (false as boolean) {
    console.log("something");
}
```

Comment: What additional type safety is gained when `1 == 2` isn't compilable? That this concept comes at a price is apparent from your example `false as boolean`.

Answer (score 4):

Typescript can create a type from any constant value. This when combined with union types creates a very powerful way of expressing what a function takes as an argument for example:

```
function doStuff(p : "yes"| 1| true| "no"| 0| false ){

}

doStuff("maybe"); //Error
doStuff(3); // Error
doStuff(1) ; //OK
```

You are experiencing the unfortunate side effect that errors such as yours instead of being reports as `expression is always false` turn into type compatibility errors instead.

Comment: Treating each different number literal as a singleton type isn't powerful. It's odd and limiting.

Comment: It is limiting where you want it to be limiting, Typescript is all about imposing limits on what you can write making sure that what you write is valid. 1 == 2 is probably an error, passing a function an argument it does not expect such as the example above is an error. Typescript want to catch as many of these at compile time instead of runtime

Comment: I know the purpose of a static type system. But apparently TypeScript doesn't know polymorphism.

Comment: Both types 1 and 2 are assignable to number (the base type). This is polymorphism. In C# for example you can't assign a `Triangle` to a `Square` even if they both inherit `Shape`, as expected. It is the same principle. I am curious where you see a problem with this implementation.

Comment: Literal type singletons add complexity without providing reasonable benefits. If I have `a = true; b = true` it doesn't give me anything if the types are literally bound to their values. It is just a matter of value equality and the type system should merely protect me from comparing different types.

Comment: I agree with you about the complexity part, I fear that Typescript has to many features to easily pick up. But I do see value in this feature, I have worked with frameworks where the documentation says that the parameter can be yes or no or 1 or 0 or true or false, and it is nice to have that directly in the method signature, and have to caller either pass in those values, or make an explicit choice that this number I know will be an acceptable value to the function.

Comment: OK, I can see your point. If you are interested in type systems and since TypeScript is rather OO/subtyping, you might want to look into functional type systems that include parametric/bounded polymorphism, smart constructors and sum types.